# Android Application Crash Management using Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, xamarin

**General Scenario :**

While developing android application using xamarin, we tend to crash the application multiple times and this behavior is perfectly acceptable and normal.

But some time, when i navigate from 1st Activity to 2nd activity. and on 2nd activity if the application crashes, then on next run the application starts from the 2nd activity, where as it should start from the 1st activity. please note 1st activity : mainLauncher property is set to TRUE.

**Application :**

```
1 st Activity = Splash Screen;

2 nd Activity = Login Screen; [sets a global appication variable User ID]

3 rd Activity = User Profile [fetch data from database using User ID];

4 th Activity = preference page, settings which saves username n password from login form.
```

==============================================================================

**Problem :**

While running application the flow should go according to the given activities, when I enter correct credential on my login page then it saves my **(int)UserID**. and using this UserID I fetch the details of the user and display them on 3rd Activity.

but some times if the application crashes on the 3rd activity, and when I restart the application it does not starts from the Splash Screen, but from the activity it crashed(*3rd activity*) on or the previous activity(*caller of 3rd Activity,not always LoginForm*) from where the activity was called.

now the problem is that as i never received a LoginPage so never entered the login details so the **(int)UserID** is set to **0/NULL**, and thus *no data is fetched from the database*. Showing all fields on the 3rd activity(profile activity) as **Blank**

**My Handling Solution:**

so to handle This I override the **OnResume()** and check for **UserID**, i.e *if userID is 0* then load the **LoginScreen**. This works perfectly fine.

but now when i manually exit the application by killing the processID, still the Profile screen remains, it calls the OnResume(); again. As I had logged out it again load the login screen,....

and this goes on in loop. Now I am unable to exit the application by killing the `processID`, Please help me find the solution for this problem

Sorry for such a long question, but I didn't find any way to explain better than this, hope my friends won't mind.

Comment: You can also find the same solution on xamarin forum

http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/4068/how-to-handle-application-crashes

Answer (score 0):

(Answered by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> I managed to Solve this problem and will explain with an simple example.
>
> **class clsMainProjectLibrary :**
>
> This is the main library which we defined a function that can be called in any of the activity so that we could reuse the code.

```
clsMainProjectLibrary
{
  //This variable is set by the calling activity to check if user has opt for exiting the     application or actually application has crashed.
  public static bool isExit; 
  // My Global Application variable which get assigned when user successfully log-ins else is
  public static int intUserID; 
    public Intent ApplicationCrashHandler(Activity actForm)
    {
      if (clsFunctionaLibA.isExit == false)
      {
       Intent intentMyFirstForm = new Intent(actForm,typeof(actMyFistForm));
       intentMyFirstForm.SetFlag(ActivityFlags.ClearTop & ActivityFlags.NewTask);
       return intentMyFirstForm;
      }
      else
      {
       Intent blankIntent = new Intent();
       blankIntent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
       int intPID = Android.OS.Process.MyPid();
       Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(intPID);
       return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

> **actMyCustomActivity.cs : **
>
> This is my custom activity, in this activity we will call our `ApplicationCrashHandler()`. So whenever this activity is crashed or started by default then it should load my `actMyFirstForm`

```
[Activity(Label = "Profile Details",MainLauncher=false)]
 public class actMyCustomActivity : Activity
 {
   clsMainProjectLibrary objMainProjectLibrary = new clsMainProjectLibrary();
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
   {
     // Put your all code here... what u want
   }

   protected override void OnResume()
   {
    if (clsMainProjectLibrary.intUserID == 0)
    {
      StartActivity(objMainProjectLibrary.ApplicationCrashHandler(this));
    }
    base.OnResume();
   }

   public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
   {
     //here you have your exit Menu.
   }

   public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
   {
     //code for user clicking on Exit.
     :
     :
     case 'Exit' : 
                  clsFunctionaLibA.isExit = true;
                  int intPID = Android.OS.Process.MyPid();
                  Android.OS.Process.KillProcess(intPID);

     :
     :
   }
 }
```

> ====================================================================
>
> ** This code works for me...**
>
> It checks if `UserID = 0` or has some Value, and if the user has clicked on Exit from menu. we need to exit the application totally without loading our Required screen.
>
> This might not the be the Best Solution, or recommended solution, but this works for me....
>
> If there is any legit method to do about this problem please, let me no so that I could modify my code accordingly .